# Restarting a cluster on databricks

Tags: bash, azure, command-line, databricks

I'm trying to restart an existing cluster in Databricks on Azure using databricks-cli.

I'm using the following command:

```
databricks clusters restart {"cluster_id": "0710-121255-liner30"}
```

But it gives giving me this error

```
Error: Missing option "--cluster-id".
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error message explains the issue: you need to have a `--cluster-id` parameter, not a JSON object after the option `restart`.

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may check the syntax to restart the databricks cluster:

```
 restart          Restarts a Databricks cluster.
    Options:
      --cluster-id CLUSTER_ID  Can be found in the URL at https://<databricks-instance>/?o=<16-digit-number>#/setting/clusters/$CLUSTER_ID/configuration.
```

**Invalid syntax:** `databricks clusters restart {"cluster_id": "0710-121255-liner30"}`

**Correct syntax:** `databricks clusters restart --cluster-id 0802-090441-honks846`

[image]

Reference: [Azure Databricks - Cluster CLI](https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/dev-tools/databricks-cli.html#clusters-cli)